# SQL Server 2014 Connection string is not valid [87] in php

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I upgraded from SQL SERVER 2008 from SQL SERVER 2014.

I am already using SQL SERVER 2008 with PHP. After the upgrade from SQL SERVER 2008 to SQL SERVER 2014 it doesn't seem to be working. It's showing the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network
>   Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: What is the connection string (but pleas obscure the password)?

Comment: this is connection string used ---

Comment: $server = "servername/instancename";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"***", "UID"=>"***", "PWD"=>"****" );
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo );
 
 if ($conn === false) die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
echo "Successfully connected!";

Comment: Please edit the question, that much code is unreadable in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the \ in $server

and first give UID & PWD then Database

```
 $server = "servername\instancename"; 
 $connectionInfo = array(  "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"****", "Database"=>"", );
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo ); 
 if ($conn === false)
 die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
 echo "Successfully connected!";
```

this will working..